# Clarification as to why EXECUTE AS USER/LOGIN is not returning the expected results?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

I am running the following query against a database:

```
execute as user = 'domain\username'
select * from fn_my_permissions(null, 'DATABASE')
order by subentity_name, permission_name
revert;
```

But the following error gets thrown:

`Cannot execute as the database principal because the principal "dev\spadmin" does not exist, this type of principal cannot be impersonated, or you do not have permission.`

The user is the dbo of the database, and when I open up the properties in management studio, I can see that it is associated with that login.  Running `EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'domain\username'` does return results, on the other hand.  And if I explicitly run `EXECUTE AS USER = 'dbo'`, I get results.  I also have a different database where this same scenario returns results with both `EXECUTE AS USER` and `EXECUTE AS LOGIN`.

In another scenario with a different user, I have ran `EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'domain\username'` and I do not get results, but I do get results with `EXECUTE AS USER = 'domain\username'`.

Both users in these scenarios are associated with logins that are members of `db_owner` for the database.

Can anybody tell me why these queries are not returning the results that I expect?  And let me know if I am missing any important information.  Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that because the Login `domain\username` is the dbo of the database, that *also* means that the name of their corresponding User within that database is `dbo` and ***not*** `domain\username`.

Comment: The thing that confuses me is that `EXECUTE AS USER = 'domain\username'` works on another database where the user is the dbo but not on this database.  Any idea why that might be?

Comment: My guess would be that they used to be a non-DBO user and later became the owner of the database, but their old User entry left behind.  That's not supposed to happen but I have definitely seen it.

Comment: I checked to see what the differences were between the two users.  The user where the `EXECUTE AS USER` query wasn't working has the server roles of dbcreator, public, and security admin.  The user where the query worked had all server roles.  Once I gave it the same roles as the other user, I got the same results as the other user.

Comment: Then the problem was probably that your original execution context lacked the permission to Impersonate the user.

Answer (score 1):

run `ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::[<yourdb>] TO [sa]`

Comment: I do not wish to alter anything about the database, because the application running this query will eventually be used on client machines.  I simply want to obtain the permissions of a specific user/login to determine if it is configured correctly.

Unless I misunderstand what that query is actually doing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error for a stored procedure that I wrote.

I found the error was caused by the way I had specified the database name in the query

```
SELECT emp_no 
FROM   db_name.employee 
WHERE  emp_no = 1234
```

I was executing the procedure on `db_name2` once I removed the database name from my script

```
SELECT emp_no 
FROM   employee 
WHERE  emp_no = 1234
```

it worked fine.

I don't think the reduced access rights of the log allow for the use of other databases or the `use db_name` command.